# How to get the state of Durable entities in Azure using http function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am new to Azure Functions and durable entities. I am trying to do a small demo project which is building an entity and using http function to get that entities' state. But when I am trying to get access to that entity, it keeps showing "null";

Here is my piece of code:

```
\\bedManager.cs
namespace HospitelBedManager
{
    public static class BedManager
    {
        [FunctionName(nameof(AssignBed))]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> AssignBed(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")]
            HttpRequest req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableEntityClient durableEntityClient,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var bedNumber = req.Query["bedNumber"];
            var entityId = new EntityId(nameof(BedEntity),bedNumber);
            
            var bedEntity = await durableEntityClient.ReadEntityStateAsync<BedEntity>(entityId);
            
            await durableEntityClient.SignalEntityAsync(entityId, nameof(BedEntity.AssignBedAsync));
            Console.WriteLine("***" + bedEntity.EntityExists + "***");
            return new OkObjectResult($"Bed {bedNumber} has been set to occupied.");
        }
    }
}
```

```
Bedentity.cs
namespace HospitelBedManager.Entities
{
    public class BedEntity
    {
        public string BedNumber { get; set; }
        public bool IsOccupied { get; set; }
        
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public BedEntity(ILogger logger, string bedNumber)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            BedNumber = bedNumber;
        }
        
        [FunctionName(nameof(BedEntity))]
        public static async Task HandleEntityOperation(
            [EntityTrigger] IDurableEntityContext context,
            ILogger logger)
        {
            await context.DispatchAsync<BedEntity>(logger, context.EntityKey);
        }
        
        public Task<bool> IsOccupiedBedAsync()
        {
            var IsOccupied = BedNumber == "123";
            return Task.FromResult(IsOccupied);
        }
        
        public Task AssignBedAsync(string bedNumber)
        {
            IsOccupied = true;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that this kind of thing is a great fit for durable entities, although you said it's only an example. However, durable entities are better suited for things like state machines or circuit breakers. They are not great as substitutes for databases. Having said that when your function runs with a bed number the first time there is no bed entity state to read, you get null. i.e in the code you have presented you do not initialize a bed entity anywhere.

If you could consider a bed as a state machine the initial state would presumably be unoccupied/available. Once booked it would transition to state unavailable.